How do I assign a value for an empty destructured object in ES6?
I've got the following:
const { var1 } = requestObj1 //requestObj1.var1 = {} => and hence return {}
var1.anotherVariable = reqObj2?.anotherObj?.value //return error: cannot read property of undefined.


requestObj1: { headers: {}, method: 'GET', timeout: 30000, uri: 'some url'}

I don't think we can use chaining on an undefined object.

Please add the values of requestObj1 and reqObj2 to the code.

The only destructuring is {var1}. The second line uses optional chaining, not destructuring.

@Barmar "requestObj1" is a dynamic object, its values varies based on the request.

So? Show a sample value that's causing the error.

duplicate: destructuring assignment default value.

You can specify a default value, so that var1 is never undefined:
const { var1={} } = requestObj1
var1.anotherVariable = reqObj2?.anotherObj?.value 


This worked for me awesome. Can I know what this technique is called in es6. I have never seen this kind of defaulting value before. This works perfect for a dynamic objects.

Notice this still fails for requestObj1 = { var1: null }
